# counting unrepeated registers group by day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've this table:

```
DATE        REGCODE1  REGCODE2    REGCODE 3   REGCODE4    
02/01/15    70771      60771       40771        30771
02/01/15    null       60775        null         null  
02/01/15    70855      null        40771         null  
02/01/15    null       null         null         null
03/01/15    70771      55002       66554        66555 
03/01/15    70772      55002       65557        66555   
05/01/15    null       55002       57777        30771  
05/01/15    70855      null        null          null
05/01/15    70826      null        null          9
```

and i need to Count the different `REGCODEs` grouping by date, but if one of them is repeated in one of the PREVIOUS dates, this one don´t count anymore

so, i need something like that:

```
DATE     COUNT(REGCODE1)  COUNT(REGCODE2)  COUNT(REGCODE3) COUNT(REGCODE4)
02/01/15      2                2                1                1
03/01/15      1                1                2                1
05/01/15      1                0                1                1
```

Thank u very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only count a regcode once - for the earliest date. Get rid of regcode duplicates first then and in the second step group by date. Like this:

```
SELECT "DATE", count(*)
  FROM (SELECT "REGCODE1", min("DATE") as "DATE"
          FROM regcodes
         WHERE "REGCODE1" IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY "REGCODE1")
 GROUP BY "DATE"
 ORDER BY "DATE";
```

This was for a single regcode only, you've got to join 4 subqueries of this type to get the result you want:

```
SELECT "DATE", count("REGCODE1"), count("REGCODE2"), count("REGCODE3"), count("REGCODE4")
  FROM (SELECT min("DATE") as "DATE", "REGCODE1", NULL AS "REGCODE2", NULL AS "REGCODE3", NULL AS "REGCODE4"
          FROM regcodes WHERE "REGCODE1" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY "REGCODE1"
         UNION ALL
        SELECT min("DATE") as "DATE", NULL, "REGCODE2", NULL, NULL
          FROM regcodes WHERE "REGCODE2" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY "REGCODE2"
         UNION ALL
        SELECT min("DATE") as "DATE", NULL, NULL, "REGCODE3", NULL
          FROM regcodes WHERE "REGCODE3" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY "REGCODE3"
        UNION ALL
        SELECT min("DATE") as "DATE", NULL, NULL, NULL, "REGCODE4"
          FROM regcodes WHERE "REGCODE4" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY "REGCODE4")
 GROUP BY "DATE"
 ORDER BY "DATE";
```

And here's [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59bba4/1).